# Reading text from a file Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I read word data from a text file and then each click of the button read another line from that file (another word)? Please reply.

Comment: will it help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-a-simple-text-file-in-an-android-app-using-kotlin ??

Comment: Use google... rather than questioning here like this. In SO, everyone helps for source code(where the error is how to solve it).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the whole file in advance, separated by lines (`List<String>`) and save the current line in a variable. With Kotlin it’s super easy:

```
var currentLine = 0
lateinit var lines: List<String>

fun readLines() {
    lines = File(“PATH_HERE”).readLines()
}

fun processLine() {
    if (lines.isEmpty()) return

    val line = lines[currentLine++]
    if (currentLine >= lines.size()) {
        currentLine = 0
    }

    // Do something with the line
}
```

Just be sure you call `readLines()` before `processLine()`